# Single column image at the top and 2-column image at the bottom

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I am trying to make my page of a 2-column document look like this:

[image]

This is my code (I am using dbfloatix for !b command):

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{}
    \caption{A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[]{}}
    \caption{B}
\end{figure*}
```

This works but it puts image B on the next page no matter what I try..
I need to make the two images stay on one page.

Comment: Maybe try with the `strip` environment (`cuted` package)  which temporarily leaves two column mode, for image B. The figure* environment is always plaved on the  page that follows the code.

Comment: This has helped. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean you want white space between the figures or you want normal document text?

Comment: Yeah there is text everywhere like normal document, no white spaces, sorry for not making that clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double column figures always go to the next page you can (sometimes) use `\suppresfloats[t]` to stop the single one appearing on the page before but the timing can be tricky.

Or.... put the spanning float first, then it will take the single column float with it to the next page, then just fix up the numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section {zzz}

\lipsum[1]

\addtocounter{figure}{1}
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{double column zzz}
\end{figure*}

\addtocounter{figure}{-2}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{single column zzz}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{1}

\lipsum[2-14]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Yes, I saw that putting the bottom figure before the top did the job but messed my numbering. So this is great as I only need to add few lines of code to get this to work.